# How to force a PKG installer to run a second time after i denied it to run with the necessary privileges the first time?

Tags: install, ventura, pkg

I have a legit non-app store app installer I downloaded from my VOIP business vendor portal to install called TELUS_Business_Connect.pkg (Canada VOIP Provider).. which is really just Ring Central rebranded.

When I first tried to install the pkg accidentally clicked "NO" to the security prompts that macOS needed me to allow for the PKG software to install correctly. Using all defaults.

Now when I rerun the PKG installer to retry.. it always fails and never prompts me like before.

How do I make macOS **forget** that it has ever seen this PKG before?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried a right-click on the pkg and selecting "Open..." that will often bring up the permissions prompt.

Comment: After declining the permissions asked for, you should be able to find the "Installer.app" in `System Settings > Privacy & Security > Files & Folders`.  If you toggle the switch there to 'on', the installer will be allowed to access whatever it tried to access (usually "Removable Volumes").

Comment: @Redarm answer worked exactly as stated. Was not intuitive or obvious that "installer.app" was the global problem. I kept looking for the name of the PKG itself..